# Swift: Can't insert NSObject into Array as it wants a [String] instead

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3, uicollectionview, nsobject

I have a model object called Hashtag. This simply contains a optional String variable called hashtagName. I fetch the data from my Firebase Database and append the hashtags to my fashionHashtags, which is a `[Hashtag]`. The issue I have is that I want to append that to my other categoriesArray by using the `insertElementAtIndexPath` function. I cannot do this as it wants an array of Strings and not an array of Hashtag. When I autocorrect it, it replaces it with `fashionHashtags as! [String]` but that creates another error. How do I fix this so it allows me to do so? I would like to stick to the Model Object way of doing things. Thank you guys. An answer would be highly appreciated. Code is below:

```
class Hashtag: NSObject {

    vvar hashtagName: String?
}

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

class HashtagView: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    var catagoriesArray: [String] = ["FASHION", "FOOD", "HOBBIES", "MUSIC"]

    var fashionHashtags = [Hashtag]()
    var foodHashtags = [Hashtag]()
    var hobbiesHashtags = [Hashtag]()
    var musicHashtags = [Hashtag]()

    var hashtagsArray: [String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.hashtagsArray.removeAll()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationItem.title = "Hashtag"

        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Finished", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(finishSelectingHashtags))

        self.collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView?.register(HashtagCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        self.collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)

        handleFetchFashionHashtags()
    }

    func insertElementAtIndexPath(element: [String], index: Int) {
        catagoriesArray.insert(contentsOf: element, at: index)
    }

    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if indexPath.item == 0 {
            insertElementAtIndexPath(element: fashionHashtags, index: indexPath.item + 1)

            self.collectionView?.performBatchUpdates(
                {
                    self.collectionView?.reloadSections(NSIndexSet(index: 0) as IndexSet)
            }, completion: { (finished:Bool) -> Void in

            })
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based upon my understanding, there could be a couple of different approaches.  Here would be the approach of looping through the array of Hashtag objects and appending the hashtagName string property to the categoriesArray of strings.

```
    for hashTagItem in fashionHashtags {
        if let hashTag = hashTagItem.hashtagName {
             // Appends to categoriesArray as a string
             categoriesArray.append(hashTag)
        }
    }
```

Another approach would be to build a set of strings and then insert it as it makes sense.

```
    var hashTagString: [Strings] = []
    for hashTagItem in fashionHashtags {
        if let hashTag = hashTagItem.hashtagName {
             hashTagStrings.append(hashTag)
        }
    }
    // Insert or add the hash tag strings as it makes sense
    categoriesArray += hashTagStrings  // Add all at once if it makes sense
```

Comment: basically I have a categoriesArray and I have an array of Hashtags. The hashtag object holds a hashtagNames. Them names are appended to the fashionArray as a bunch of strings. I want to then append that fashionArray to the categoriesArray but it wants it to be an array of strings instead